# Is there a calibre $\aleph_1$ Moore space which is not separable

Tags: gn.general-topology, counterexamples

A topological space has *calibre* $\aleph_1$ if for every uncountable sequence $\langle U_\alpha\mid\alpha\lt\aleph_1\rangle$ of nonempty open sets $U_\alpha\subset X$, there is an uncountable subfamily $\Lambda\subset\aleph_1$ with $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Lambda}U_\alpha\neq\emptyset$.

Is there a calibre $\aleph_1$ Moore space which is not separable?

(Under CH, the answer is no, since every first countable calibre $\aleph_1$ space is separable.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frank Tall proved that under $MA+\neg CH$ there is a regular first-countable space with caliber $\omega_1$ which is not separable. (see *Tall, Franklin D.*, First countable spaces with caliber $\aleph_1$ may or may not be separable, Set-theor. Topol., Vol. dedic. to M.K. Moore, 353-358 (1977). [ZBL0382.54003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0382.54003).)

Applying the Moore Machine to Tall's example you get what you're looking for.

Comment: Does the Moore space generated by using Moore machine for $X$ keep property calibre $\aleph_1$ if $X$ is calibre  $\aleph_1$? Could you provide a link or paper about this for me?